# 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to filter the grid view by Id, but something error in my syntax

This my HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index(int searching)
{
   return View(db.ex_op.Where( x => x.id_ats.Contains(searching) || searching = null).ToList());
}
```

this my HomeView:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searching")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

this my Error:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable,int)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable' ```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You trying to call `int.Contains` while you'd rather need `==`, i.e. `Where( x => x.id_ats == searching)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change from `.Contains()` to `==` to be able to compare `int`

```
public ActionResult Index(int searching)
{
   return View(db.ex_op.Where( x =>  searching == null || x.id_ats == searching ).ToList());
}
```

or You still want to filter by `Contains`, you can convert `.ToString()` along with change type of param to `string` like this

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{
   return View(db.ex_op.Where( x => searching == null || x.id_ats.ToString().Contains(searching)).ToList());
}
```

**Updated**

Basically, Unless you use (int? searching) *What means nullable int*, the Default value of `int` is Zero, So you no need to check `null`.

```
db.ex_op.Where( x => x.id_ats == searching).ToList()
```

Comment: Hey, `searching == null` instead of `searching = null`

Comment: btw `searching == null` doesn't make sense since `searching` is `int` what means the condition is always true (int is never `null`). `int?` may be null though.

Comment: Yeah, It should be zero when having no value, sir.